# Is there a shortform way to replace two characters inside a string in C#?

Tags: c#

Given:

```
var x = "abc";
var x = "[abc]";
```

I coded the following to remove the [ and ] characters.

```
x1 = x.Replace("[", "");
x2 = x1.Replace("]", "");
```

Is there some way that looks more clean to do this? Can I for example string one replace after the other? Note that the [ and ] if they appear will be found always at the start and the end of the string.

Comment: The title is misleading since you don't want to remove chars _inside_ a string but only _at the start and the end of the string_.

Answer (score 8):

```
string newstring = x.Trim('[', ']');
```

Comment: Will only work for this example. But what if they are in between?

Comment: in question square brackets are clearly written at end and start of string so i just answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I for example string one replace after the other?

Yes:

```
var result = x.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Replace() returns a string, you can chain the expressions together:

```
var x1 = x.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
```

Comment: There's a `string` or a `var` declaration missing.

Comment: @Tomalak good catch - it's clearly still too early on a Monday morning! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the [ and ] if they appear will be found always at the start and the end of the string.

You'd need to use a regular expression to make sure that *strictly* no other square brackets are replaced:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(x, @"^\[|\]$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

The probably most efficient approach with large strings and many chars to remove:

```
String input = "[abc]";
String removed = input.RemoveChars(new[] { '[', ']' });

public static String RemoveChars(this string input, char[] charsToRemove)
{
    Array.Sort(charsToRemove);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (Array.BinarySearch(charsToRemove, c) < 0)
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You must be kidding! Try benchmarking this and `Trim('[', ']')`.

Comment: @Henrik: Then benchmark with a very large string and many chars to remove. It depends on the use case (edited).

Answer (score 0):

```
string newstring = x.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use TrimStart and TrimEnd:

```
string x = "[abc]";
string result = x.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
```

This will be the simplest way and will have the best performance.

Here I make the assumption that '[' will be in the beginning and ']' will be in the end.